# Merge and synonymize [nelmio-alice] and [alice-fixtures]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[nelmio-alice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nelmio-alice) and [alice-fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alice-fixtures) refer to the same thing:

https://github.com/nelmio/alice

Neither has a ton of activity (46 and 36 questions respectively), but the former has a few more.

These two should be merged and synonymized.